# No content in the window after applying windowedFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink, am trying to do some exercises, when I used window with kafka connector, I met a problem.

The code is like this:

```scala
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

.....

// a KeyedStream with name as the key
val eventsStream: KeyedStream[CustomedObject, String] = env
  .addSource[CustomedObject](source.getSource)
  .keyBy(c.get("name"))

// defines a Sliding window assigner with event time
val windowedStream: WindowedStream[CustomedObject, String, TimeWindow] = eventsStream.window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2L), Time.seconds(1L)))

// applys a window function
val result = windowedStream.apply(
  (key, window, input: Iterable[CustomedObject], out: Collector[(String, TimeWindow)]) => {
    out.collect((key, window))
  }
)
```

Problem: when I tried **eventsStream.print()**, there are outputs in the console, but when I tried to **result.print()**, there are no outputs.

Infos:
the key exists and has value in each event

Could somebody tell me why there is no output of contents of each window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event time window fires when the watermark for the stream reaches the end of the window. If that isn't happening, then there is probably a problem with the watermarks. Either the source needs to take care of generating appropriate watermarks, or you need to make it happen in your application. See [event time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/event_time.html) and [watermarks](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html) for more info on these topics.

Updated with a summary to hopefully avoid any confusion:

Event time timestamps and watermarks are longs that *usually* represent milliseconds since the Epoch, but event time is a logical, monotonically increasing clock, and Flink doesn't care what the values actually represent.

Unlike processing time, which relentless progresses forward on its own, event time stands still until advanced by *watermarks*. The current watermark is the current value of the event time clock, which typically lags behind the max timestamp seen so far by some bounded delay (this delay is the maximum out-of-orderness that will be accommodated before events are considered late).

When your application is operating in event time, Flink needs to know the timestamp associated with each stream element, and the current watermark. *Timestamp extractors* and *watermark generators* serve this role, and Flink provides two built-in approaches for doing this that you can extend.

Unless your data source has already extracted the timestamps for you, with both `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks` and `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` you will need to implement an `extractTimestamp(MyEvent element, long previousElementTimestamp)` method that Flink will call on every stream element to get its timestamp.

The difference between these two is that **`AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks`** has a checkAndGetNextWatermark() method that is called for every stream element, with the expectation that some elements are special (like punctuation marks), and that these special elements will be used to generate watermarks. By contrast, with **`AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks`**, its getCurrentWatermark() method is called every `ExecutionConfig.getAutoWatermarkInterval()` milliseconds to generate a watermark, with the expectation that some state has been kept as a side effect of the calls to extractTimestamp() that can be used to generate watermarks (`BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` does this by remembering the maximum timestamp seen so far in the stream).

Answer (score 0):

@alpinegizmo Thank you so much for your reply, you are right, I want to make a small summary for the other newers.

Two points to be noticed:

1. Timestamps and watermarks are defined as **longs** that represent the
       **milliseconds** since the Epoch (midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC), which means it should be something like `1511866730000L`
2. Difference between `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks` and
       `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks`:

**AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks**: If elements **already** carry a timestamps when they were created, you want to use them as the timestamps, so use `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks`, because it is "*punctuated*";

**AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks**: Use this class to generate watermarks in a periodical interval. At most every xx milliseconds (configured via `ExecutionConfig.getAutoWatermarkInterval()`), the system will call the `getCurrentWatermark()` method to probe for the next watermark value. So it is system **automatically** generates a timestimps for each event for you, it is "*periodic*".

I was confused about the punctuated and periodic, I thought punctuated means the timestamp will be saved somewhere, it is permanant storage.

I hope this can help other rookies！

Comment: That's not quite right, so I've expanded my answer to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: @alpinegizmo That's perfect, thank you very much, I should learn more from you, maybe you can recommend some books of flink for me ?

Comment: You're welcome! https://data-artisans.com/download-introduction-apache-flink-book and http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920057321.do. Also http://training.data-artisans.com/

Comment: @alpinegizmo Thank you very much!